# Memory leak : ObjectListView TreeListView cache is keeping a reference alive, how to disable?

Tags: c#, winforms, garbage-collection, objectlistview

This is happening with the NuGet package ObjectListView.Official 2.9.1, with .NET Framework 4.7.2.

I can't figure out how to dispose of the objects that are loaded inside a TreeListView, even after disposing the TreeListView itself, with no references present elsewhere. The objects are not even on the GC finalizer queue.

Below is a simple reproducible example I've been doing tests with.

```
public FormTreeList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        nodes.Add(new Node("Node" + i.ToString()));
    }
    olvColumnValue.AspectGetter = delegate (object x) { return ((Node)x).Value; };
    this.treeListView1.SetObjects(nodes);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        //Disposing of the references
        treeListView1.ClearCachedInfo();
        treeListView1.CanExpandGetter = null;
        treeListView1.ChildrenGetter = null;
        treeListView1.ParentGetter = null;
        treeListView1.Columns.Clear();
        olvColumnValue.AspectGetter = null;
        olvColumnValue = null;
        treeListView1.Roots = null;
        treeListView1 = null;
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

public class Node
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Node(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

This is a graph from RedGate ANTS tool showing what is still holding a reference to one of the `Node`, after the `FormTreeList` was disposed.

[image: GC Graph]

I can figure out that the cachedLayoutEvent is keeping my references alive, but how can I unsubscribe from it since it is private?

Is this a bug from ObjectListView?

Comment: In order for Dispose to be called follow the well documented dispose pattern and create the object in a using block.